# How to update gridview after adding records in Gridview and VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my application, im adding records using separate form. After adding records, the main page will get updated and show the latest addition in first row. But in my coding, it is not happening.
Only if I move to next page and come back to first page, the latest record is showing in top.
Loading Main Page (form_admin.vb)

```
Private Sub admin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 


        ' module function connect to dbms
        mod_sqlconnect.connect()

        ds.Clear()
        mod_datagrid.gridview("risk") ' module function to use MySQLAdapter

        Adpt.Fill(ds, "risk")
        'Set the start and max records. 
        pageSize = 20
        maxRec = ds.Tables("risk").Rows.Count
        PageCount = maxRec \ pageSize

        ' Adjust the page number if the last page contains a partial page.
        If (maxRec Mod pageSize) > 0 Then
            PageCount = PageCount + 1
        End If

        currentPage = 1
        recNo = 0

        LoadPage()

    End Sub

    Public Sub LoadPage()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim startRec As Integer
        Dim endRec As Integer
        Dim dtTemp As DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow

        dtTemp = ds.Tables("risk").Clone

        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            endRec = maxRec
        Else
            endRec = pageSize * currentPage
        End If

        startRec = recNo

        'Copy the rows from the source table to fill the temporary table.
        For i = startRec To endRec - 1
            dtTemp.ImportRow(ds.Tables("risk").Rows(i))
            recNo = recNo + 1
        Next

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dtTemp


    End Sub
```

Insert Form to add new reocrds

```
Private Sub ADD_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click


        'coding to check if all data is entered ……… hided


            'declarations
            Dim ni_newindex As Integer
            Dim ri_insert As MySqlDataReader
            Dim cmdi_insert As New MySqlCommand


            'adding new risk using insert command
            conn.Open()
            cmdi_insert = New MySqlCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO risk VALUES ({19},'{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}',{4},'{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}',{11},{12},'{13}','{14}',{15},{16},'{17}','{18}', curdate(),NULL );", i1.SelectedItem, i2.Text, i3.SelectedItem, i4.SelectedItem, i5.Text, i6.SelectedItem, i7.SelectedItem, i8.SelectedItem, i9.SelectedItem, i10.SelectedItem, i11.SelectedItem, i12.Text, i13.Text, i14.Text, i15.Text, i16.Value, i17.Text, i18.Text, i19.Text, ni_newindex), conn)

            cmdi_insert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            conn.Close()


            ds.Clear()
            mod_datagrid.gridview("risk")
            Adpt.Fill(ds, "risk")

            form_admin.currentPage = 1
            form_admin.recNo = 0
            form_admin.pageSize = 20

            form_admin.LoadPage()
            form_admin.DataGridView1.Refresh()  'Refreshing gridview is not updating the gridview


            Me.Close()

        End If
    End Sub
```

But if I move to next page through paging coding and com back to same page, the record is there.

Coding of Next page and previosu page:

```
Private Sub btnNextbutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNextbutton.Click     

        currentPage = currentPage + 1

        If currentPage > PageCount Then
            currentPage = PageCount           
        End If

        LoadPage()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click

        If currentPage = PageCount Then
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 2)
        End If

        currentPage = currentPage - 1
        If currentPage < 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("You are at the First Page!")
            currentPage = 1
            Return
        Else
            recNo = pageSize * (currentPage - 1)
        End If

        LoadPage()   
 End Sub
```

When I debug, after adding new record, when I check  here `dtTemp.ImportRow(ds.Tables("risk").Rows(i))` , it shows the latest addition in watch window ,But gridview not showing that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 form_admin.DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

Try

```
form_admin.DataGridView1.Datasouce = Nothing
form_admin.DataGridView1.DataSource = dtTemp
```

.Refresh only repaints the grid and doesn't touch its data.